# exact_extract unsupported geometry type error

Tags: r

When I ran  `exact_extract(rasterlayer, sf_object)` I was getting the following error:

`in CPP_exact_extract(x, weights, wkb, default_value, default_weight,  :  Unsupported geometry type.`

I wasn't sure what was going on, since my other extracts with nearly identical sf objects worked. I figured it out, so documenting my answer here.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To identify the issue I looked up the geometry types in my sf_object and compared them to the geometries contained in extractions that worked:

```
st_geometry_type(sf_object) %>% as.data.frame(.) %>% distinct(.) %>% View(.)
```

It turns out `exact_extract()` doesn't like `"GEOMETRYCOLLECTION"` shapes.

So next, I filtered out these types of geometric shapes from my `sf_object`, and afterwards running `exact_extract()` worked.

```
dplyr::filter(st_is(sf_object,c("POLYGON","MULTIPOLYGON")))
```

Comment: It should be OK with `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION` provided that they're polygonal.